# storybook build error You may need to refresh the browser

Tags: typescript, storybook

I use typescript, react, and next.js.
I introduced storybook and launched storybook with yarn storybook. When I ran yarn storybook the next day, I got an error.

error

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
ERR! .storybook/main.ts:1:1 - error TS1208: 'main.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.
ERR! 
ERR! 1 const path = require('path');
ERR!   ~~~~~
ERR! 
ERR!     at createTSError (/Users/taichi/de/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:434:12)
ERR!     at storybookDevServer (/Users/taichi/de/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/dev-server.js:496:21)
ERR!     at buildDevStandalone (/Users/taichi/de/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/build-dev.js:317:33)
ERR!  .storybook/main.ts:1:1 - error TS1208: 'main.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.
ERR! 
ERR! 1 const path = require('path');
ERR!   ~~~~~
ERR! 

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.
```

addition
This is the main.ts file

```
const path = require('path');

const toPath = (_path) => path.join(process.cwd(), _path);

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../**/*.stories.@(ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  typescript: {
    check: false,
    checkOptions: {},
    reactDocgen: 'react-docgen-typescript',
    reactDocgenTypescriptOptions: {
      shouldExtractLiteralValuesFromEnum: true,
      propFilter: (prop) => (prop.parent ? !/node_modules/.test(prop.parent.fileName) : true),
    },
  },
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      resolve: {
        ...config.resolve,
        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
          '@emotion/core': toPath('node_modules/@emotion/react'),
          'emotion-theming': toPath('node_modules/@emotion/react'),
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
```

adding ts-ignore

> ERROR in ./.storybook/preview.tsx-generated-config-entry.js Module not
> found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.filter.js' in
> '/Users/taichi/de/.storybook'  @
> ./.storybook/preview.tsx-generated-config-entry.js 5:0-45  @ multi
> ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js
> ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./.storybook/preview.tsx-generated-config-entry.js
> ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
> ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined
>
> ERROR in ./.storybook/preview.tsx-generated-config-entry.js Module not
> found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.for-each.js' in
> '/Users/taichi/de/.storybook'  @
> ./.storybook/preview.tsx-generated-config-entry.js 7:0-47  @ multi
> ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js
> ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./.storybook/preview.tsx-generated-config-entry.js
> ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
> ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined
>
> ERROR in ./src/components/Button.stories.tsx Module not found: Error:
> Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.object.assign.js' in
> '/Users/taichi/de/src/components'  @
> ./src/components/Button.stories.tsx 2:0-45  @ . sync
> ^.(?:(?:^|/|(?:(?:(?!(?:^|/).).)*?)/)(?!.)(?=.)[^/]*?.stories.(ts|tsx))$
> @ ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js  @ multi
> ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js
> ./.storybook/storybook-init-framework-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/preset/addArgs.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/preset/addParameter.js-generated-other-entry.js
> ./.storybook/preview.tsx-generated-config-entry.js
> ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
> ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined

Comment: Is your `main.ts` file empty??

Comment: Added main.ts file

Comment: Found this issue that seems related to your problem: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/9775. Maybe you can try to add `// @ts-ignore` at the beginning of your `main.ts` file.

Comment: I got an error when I added ts-ignore.

Comment: @yut I remember having the same error in one of my project. It was fixed by adding this in `.storybook/main.js`: 

`webpackFinal: (config) => {
    // Linked to https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11255
    // Should be fixed by Storybook 6.2.0-alpha.1
    config.resolve.alias["core-js/modules"] =
      "@storybook/core/node_modules/core-js/modules";
    config.resolve.alias["core-js/features"] =
      "@storybook/core/node_modules/core-js/features";
    return config;
  }`